# How do I use php $_POST to get the input from a checkbox?

Tags: php, post, input, checkbox

So, on my form I have two input methods, a text field and a checkbox.

How would I use PHP to test if the checkbox has been checked or not? Perhaps using $_POST?

I want to check if the checkbox is checked, and if it is, set a boolean to true. I have no problems setting variables, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the input from the checkbox....

So, how would I get the input from a checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p11.html

When checkboxes aren't selected, they effectively have no value, so you test it with `isset`.

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML form you have something similar:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
</form>
```

That is a checkbox named `vehicle` Now, in your PHP, you would access that with:

```
$boolean_variable = isset( $_POST['vehicle'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using the name attribute of the input when getting the posted form values.

Here is an example:

[Handling Checkbox in PHP](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" />

if (isset($_POST['foo'])) {
    // checkbox was checked
}
```

Checked checkboxes and their value are submitted in a POST request. Unchecked checkboxes aren't submitted. So if `$_POST['foo']` exists at all, it was checked.